# Order of @Cachable and @CacheEvict together on method

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I am trying to implement my custom annotation for caching. This annotation should cache method result and refresh it if some condition will be true.

```
//annotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@CacheEvict(
        value = "sessionCache",
        cacheManager = "sessionCacheManager",
        keyGenerator="classNameKeyGenerator",
        condition = "#refresh == true)",
        beforeInvocation = true)
@Cacheable(
        value = "sessionCache",
        cacheManager = "sessionCacheManager", 
        keyGenerator="classNameKeyGenerator")
public @interface SessionCacheable {

}


//usage
@SessionCachable
Object someMethod(boolean refresh)
{
}
```

But the problem is with order of running eviction and cacheable

ex. when i call:

```
someMethod(false)  // method is invoked
someMethod(false)  // method is not invoked, result is taken from cache
someMethod(true)   // method is invoked
someMethod(false)  // method is unnecessarily invoked
someMethod(false)  // method is not invoked, result is taken from cache
```

So, after third call cache is evicted correctly, but in my opinion new result should be cached after that, but is not :/ Cheers!

Comment: That's not what I see in the code. Can you create a sample project and create an issue please?

Comment: The problem was witch my STS. It didn't refresh my .war file. Caching works good to me too. Thank you so much.